# Android Monitor logcat not displaying any messages - studio version 2.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to app development and have come across an issue my course hasn't yet covered but requires.

I have created a simple app that generates a log entry using Log.i after clicking a button - see screenshot below.

[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL5MG.png)

As you may well see, no logs have been generated at all for the running emulator. This happened on an earlier app and after searching for an answer, found that going to the terminal and finding the appropriate directory, I could restart the adb using the 'kill-server' and 'start-server' commands. As this didn't work, I found the file in windows explorer and double clicked the adb.exe file. This seemed to fix the problem.

Having started another project (the one linked in the screenshot), the same problem has arisen but the same steps do not correct the issue and as such have nothing being generated in the logcat.

*beneath the emulator you see, I have nothing in the search box, the logcat is set to verbose and regex(?) is ticked.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as i'm reluctant to proceed with the course material before sorting out this issue.

Thanks.

some additional information I have found in the 'AVD' section of the 'Run' Window :

[libpng warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4pLb.png)
[adb successful start?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rRxA.png)

EDIT - [requested code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6NWD.png)

EDIT 2 - It's a bit of a bodge but it seems the adb operator command 'logcat' used in the Terminal, turns the terminal into the logcat i.e. c:..\sdk\adb logcat' - all my missing logs, including the ones generated by the buttonClicked function appear in the terminal and new logs also appear there.

[Terminal as logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTsD9.png)

Thank you for your responses but maybe someone knows a way to fix the logcat itself, i'd appreciate the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: version 2.2.1 is very old, consider updating to the latest one.

Comment: I also occasionally get some strange logcat behavior, what i normally do is (from the right drop-down) change it to `No filters` and then back to `Show only the selected app`

Comment: @digiwizkid I am using 2.2.1 due to the course material, 3.5 I have found to be very different

Comment: @a_local_nobody thanks, but that had no effect

Comment: also, as @digiwizkid said, using 2.2.1 is very very old and with all due respect, any tutorial based on 2.2.1 is probably also outdated, consider updating your android studio and getting a newer course :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody agreed but cost limitations land me with this course and with previous programming experience, all I need is to get the basics down and then the skills will be transferable - the build i'm using is also only 3 years old.

Comment: post your `activity_main.xml` code as well please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue by closing all related software, rebooting my laptop and running the adb.exe file in the `..\android\sdk\platform-tools\ directory` **before** launching the android studio.

Hope this helps if anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: i'm glad you found an answer for this :)

Comment: It's a bit irritating when I forget to do it before opening the studio, but it'll do for now, thank you and all others for participation in my first stack overflow question :D

Comment: no worries, if you ever need some help, feel free to @ me here and i'll try help you out ASAP :) i applaud anyone trying to learn android :D

Answer (score 0):

Stitches S, I think you are not calling the buttonclicked method anywhere as I haven't seen it calling in the screenshot. But if you are calling it somewhere else then try  log.d() to print that. It always works for me.

Comment: it is called in the 'onClick' property of the button in the design editor for the layout

Answer (score -2):

```
if you want to see log on button click set the buttonClick method inside the oncreate(), may be its doing nothing that's why not showing any log

    this code is working in my case:
    public class About_us extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView header, address;
        private String Info="Info";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        header=findViewById(R.id.head);
        address= findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
    }

    public void buttonClick(View view){
        Log.d( Info,"button is clickd" );
    }
}
  and this is my xml view    
 <TextView android:id="@+id/head"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/third"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/first"
            android:layout_height="30dp"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but I know the coding itself works as its almost exactly the same as when I got it working in the previous app. (only the text logged is different)

Comment: have you defined the id on which button you are clicking,because it's working in my case

Comment: public class About_us extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView header, address;
    private String Info="Info";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        header=findViewById(R.id.head);
        address= findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
    }

    public void buttonClick(View view){
        Log.d( Info,"button is clickd" );
    }
}